# How can I delegate to multiple bakers from the same Galleon Ledger account with one Tz address?

Tags: wallets, galleon

I have a Galleon wallet (v0.9.2.b) linked to my Nano Ledger. I would very much appreciate if anyone could kindly tell me how to create more than one Tz address (a manager account) so that I can delegate to multiple bakers from my Galleon Ledger Wallet. If I can create only one Tz1 address per wallet, would it mean that I could delegate my XTZs to only one baker per wallet or there is some other way to delegate to multiple bakers from one wallet (one Tz address)?
I have asked the Galleon support team this fairly straightforward question several times but they kept missing my point - I have started wondering whether they were intentionally avoiding answering my question for some reason... Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can originate multiple KT1 accounts sharing the same tz1 manager and have each KT1 account delegate to separate bakers.

However one tz1 account can only delegate to a single baker.